# Where do I put supplemental files in a Windows Service?

Tags: c#, windows-services, filepath

Ok, here's the situation. I have written a Windows service. Testing it as a "console" app has shown promising results.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out where to put a file. I have some JSON data that is critical to the application. It's in a file. I'd rather not go into too much detail on that, but just know it has to be in a file,and it's critical. It's not a config file, but it is definitely needed.

Anyway, I've added the file to my windows service project. The problem is, I can't quite figure out the right code and settings to use to put the file in the right place when the service gets installed.

This is only the second Windows service I have ever written, and the first one (years ago) didn't require supplemental files.

I wrote the service in Visual Studio 2015, on Windows 7. I will be testing it on my local machine here at the office, but it will eventually go on a production machine.

Help, please? Any ideas as to where I should put the file and how I should reference it in code?

I saw a site that said I should use the following:

```
System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

But  that didn't seem to help when I did this:

```
filePath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\myfile.ext"
```

File paths have never really been a strong suit of mine in these instances.

Any help here is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like there are three questions here: (1) where should the file go; (2) how do I get the installer to put it there; and (3) how do I reference it in the code.  If the file is read-only, I think putting it in the same directory as the service executable would be sensible.  How you would do this depends on which installer technology you're using, though it's such a common scenario that it shouldn't be difficult.  As to accessing it in the code, what you've done should work I think, but there's no real need to involve the current directory, just construct the path from `.BaseDirectory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work:

```
internal string FilePath = 
    System.IO.Path.Combine(
      System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDi‌​rectory, 
      Settings.Default.JsonFile);
```

Comment: It would be better to do `FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Settings.Default.JsonFile);`, that removes any possiblilities of issues with extra `\ ` showing up from either the `JsonFile` text or the `BaseDirectory` text.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I got this figured out. I did the following:

1. In my actual "Service" project, I added the file I needed.
2. In the "program" of the service, I did the following:

   System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);

   ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;

   ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
   {
       new MyService()
   };

   ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);

And within the class that monitors everything, I have the following:

```
internal string FilePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + Settings.Default.JsonFile;
```

Then there were a few other tweaks that I made that aren't relevant to *this* topic, but the above seemed to do the trick.

Comment: That approach is still a *bit* risky, because it might break if anything in the code (including, e.g., inside a .NET class or third-party library) decides to change the current directory.  It would be safer to use the base directory to construct the file path directly.

Comment: Thanks, Harry! I will certainly take that into advisement.